# What's a convenient way to look up a `DispatchError` in polkadot-js?

Tags: polkadot-js

A `DispatchError` will refer to a pallet and a member of the pallet's `Error` enum by index:

```
DispatchError: {"module":{"index":123,"error":456}}
```

It's tiresome and error-prone to look these up manually. How can I automate the process using the polkadot-js API or the web interface?

Comment: Is there a specific pallet you're interacting with?

Comment: Where are you seeing the dispatch error in this format? It is def something you can automate with Polkadot JS API, but maybe the web interface has not done that yet. Ultimately, you just need to map those indices to the metadata.

Comment: @forgetso No, since I'm dealing with a couple of pallets, I'm asking generally

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Oh, my bad. That's a custom format that I use in a homebrew callback logger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For polkadot-js, you can retrieve more information about the error via the event and the `findMetaError` api:

```js
events
// find/filter for failed events
.filter(({ event }) =>
  api.events.system.ExtrinsicFailed.is(event)
)
// we know that data for system.ExtrinsicFailed is
// (DispatchError, DispatchInfo)
.forEach(({ event: { data: [error] } }) => {
    if (error.isModule) {
    // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
    const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(error.asModule)
    const { docs, method, section } = decoded
    console.log(`${section}.${method}: ${docs.join(' ')}`)
    } else {
        // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
        console.log(error.toString())
    }
})
```

This was extracted from the polkadot-js cookbook recipe ["How do I get the decoded enum for an ExtrinsicFailed event"](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx/#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event).

Please note that for SUDO you have to apply a different filtering process:

```js
events
// We know this tx should result in `Sudid` event.
.filter(({ event }) =>
  api.events.sudo.Sudid.is(event)
)
// we know Sudid just returns a result
.forEach(({ event: { data: [result] } }) => {
    // check whether extrinsic was successful
    if (result.isErr) {
        const error = result.asErr
        if (error.isModule) {
            // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
            const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(error.asModule)
            const { docs, name, section } = decoded
            console.log(`Sudo Transaction Error: ${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`)
        } else {
            // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
            console.log(`Sudo Transaction Error: ${error.toString()}`)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

polkadot-js got updated to a newer version, you can follow the links provided to find the new syntax, do look into what version you're on. there's a slight difference

[Newer Version Syntax](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event)

Please note that for SUDO you have to apply a different filtering process:

[Newer Version Syntax on sudo](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-sudo-event)