# Extracting error from system.ExtrinsicFailed

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, error, typescript

I have a call to an extrinsic (in a Typescript/RxJS client) that is failing but I want to be able to catch the error that the extrinsic is throwing and not just that it failed.

```
const chainEvents: EventMap = await myExtrinsic(api, keys, somedata);
const failedEvent: Event = chainEvents["system.ExtrinsicFailed"];
```

So how do I find the specific error that the chain is throwing (i.e. from Rust)?  I want the `DispatchError`.

Furthermore, the output isn't very helpful:

```
failedEvent.index=undefined
failedEvent.method=ExtrinsicFailed
failedEvent.section=system
failedEvent.data=undefined
```

[image: Error from call to api]

[image: Error in Polkadot.js UI]

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/947/whats-a-convenient-way-to-look-up-a-dispatcherror-in-polkadot-js/956#956. And doesn't it fail at ensure_signed/ensure_root (BadOrigin)?

Comment: That code doesn't work but may reveal some clues.  I was able to get the index of the error in the enum BUT not a human readable description.  ie.  the actual enum name and the pallet where the enum is defined.  

```const failedEvent = chainEvents["system.ExtrinsicFailed"];
console.dir(failedEvent.toJSON());```

displays:

```[
  { module: { index: 61, error: '0x03000000' } },
  { weight: 288499000, class: 'Normal', paysFee: 'Yes' }
]```

where `0x03000000` means the enum at index 3 (4th when counting from 0)

Comment: There should be a more direct way of getting this or at least a way to get a human readable error enum name and pallet name.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code should work if you apply it to your custom pallet/extrinsic

```js
api.tx.balances
  .transfer(recipient, 123)
  .signAndSend(sender, ({ status, events, dispatchError }) => {
    // status would still be set, but in the case of error we can shortcut
    // to just check it (so an error would indicate InBlock or Finalized)
    if (dispatchError) {
      if (dispatchError.isModule) {
        // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
        const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
        const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

        console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
      } else {
        // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
        console.log(dispatchError.toString());
      }
    }
  });
```

Reference from https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx/#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event